# Convert variables from Excel/.txt to PHP

Tags: php, csv

Sorry, PHP/coding newbie here. I want to import an .txt/CSV file ('save as' - originally an Excel file) and use those variables in PHP.

My .txt file has three columns with three variables:

```
Number Colour Subject
12 Pink Mathematics
39 Blue Chemistry
18 Green Biology
```

I want to only display the 'Number' variable (and then subsequently find their average and take it to an output file...)

In PHP, I've firstly exploded

```
<?PHP
$lines = explode("\n", trim(file_get_contents("2017-10-17_evidence.txt")));
$headerIndex = array_flip(explode("\t", trim($lines[0])));

$Number = array($headerIndex ('Number'));

echo($Number);

?>
```

After running the code, I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\test1.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\test1.php on line 6

Comment: You are calling `$headerIndex ('Number')`. The `()` indicate this should be a function. You probably want `$headerIndex['Number']`. Also, there's a function called `fgetcsv()` in PHP: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

[fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) will get the job done for you easily.

Here's an example :

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("2017-10-17_evidence.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
// Replace ',' with your csv separator
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $number = $data[0];
        echo $number;
    }
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```